# Filter on onPremisesExtensionAttributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, microsoft-graph-api

Iam trying to make Make a GET request to the /users endpoint, using the filter parameter to specify the onPremisesExtensionAttributes value:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
.Request()
.Filter($"onPremisesExtensionAttributes/{extensionAttributeName} eq '{extensionAttributeValue}'")
.GetAsync();
```

but i got error "Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'extensionAttribute14' of resource 'User'."

i can get the uers onPremisesExtensionAttributes values and
filter works fine with other parameters like department of givenName but only show error with onPremisesExtensionAttributes

I had searched alot abut this problem and advanced querties for azure  Ad on "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=csharp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you need to add query parameter `$count` with value `true` and the header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual`

```
List<Option> requestOptions = new List<Option>();
requestOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));
requestOptions.Add(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request(requestOptions)
    .Filter($"onPremisesExtensionAttributes/{extensionAttributeName} eq '{extensionAttributeValue}'")
    .GetAsync();
```